# what is the value of results for the makeCounter()

Tags: javascript

What is the value of const result? my guess was (3, 1). This is confusing to me so any help would be appreciated.

```js
    function makeCounter() {
      let count = 0;
      return function() {
        count += 1;
        return count;
      }
    }
    const counter1 = makeCounter();
    const counter2 = makeCounter();
    counter1();
    counter1();
    
    const c1 = counter1();
    const c2 = counter2();
    const result = [c1,c2];
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [3, 1] is correct. (You can select 'run code snippit' to see it in action).

The reason here is that calling `makeCounter()` returns a **function**, with a local `count` variable initialized as zero.

Each time you call the the function returned by `makeCounter()` (i.e. `counter1`, or `counter2`), that counter's `count` is incremented.

`counter1()` is called 3 times, and `counter2()` is called once. And they are put together in an array at the end, thus [3, 1].